# How to make desktop notification sounds play?

Tags: sound, headphones, notification

I'm still relatively new to linux in general, but I have tried everything that I could see/understand online to address this issue.  The desktop notifications are not making any noise despite having working audio.  I used ToDoist to send test notifications, as well as used `notify-send test "test"` in the command line, neither make any noise.  I've ensured that the notifications were turned on, do not disturb is turned off, and that the sound will play out of my headphones when selecting the noise in the settings menu.
Ubuntu Version: 22.04.2 LTS
I am using GNOME
I do not believe that the issue is with any of the extensions I've installed, since I disabled all of them and the issue still persists.  I can't seem to find much more information on how exactly the notifications noises work online, so if anyone has any information on where I can start looking that would be greatly appreciated.